# How to fix pip install error "cl.exe failed with exit status 2:

Tags: pip, pycharm, tesseract

I tried to pip install tesseract-ocr and it shows this error:

```
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Does anyone know of a solution for this?